# Mule ESB's DataMapper custom script?

Tags: java, mule, esb, datamapper, mule-studio

I am trying to use the datamapper. I am trying to modify the script to my liking but I keep getting an error even though in the graphical visualisation it seems to be working I can see the string separated.

Here's my script

```
String streetnumaddress = input.streetAddress;
String[] parts = streetnumaddress.split(",");
String streetnumber = parts[0];
String streetaddress = parts[1];

output.blabla= "Hello";
output.telephone = input.telephoneNumber;
output.lastname= input.sn;
output.firstname= input.givenName;
output.email = input.mail;
output.city= input.l;
output.province = input.st;
output.codepostal = input.postalCode;
output.country= "CA";
output.telephoneinternet = input.telephoneNumber;
output.immeubleetsuffixe = streetnumber;
output.odonyme = streetaddress;
```

Basically the problem is the split. When I affect a String directly like output.blabla= "Hello"; This works. But the split and affectation doesn't work. Any idea how to fix it and if it's even possible in the first place to do this?

Here is my error.

```
Exception while trying to execute your data mapping.
 Check: 
• All the required libraries are declared on the classpath.
• No errors are shown on the mapping. 
• If using groovy script, check your script is valid.

Cause By:
 Component [Foreach 'array' -> 'array':FOREACH_ARRAY_ARRAY] finished with status ERROR.

org.jetel.exception.JetelRuntimeException: Component [Foreach 'array' -> 'array':FOREACH_ARRAY_ARRAY] finished with status ERROR.

    at org.jetel.graph.Node.createNodeException(Node.java:543)

    at org.jetel.graph.Node.run(Node.java:522)

    at org.jetel.graph.runtime.SingleThreadWatchDog.executePhase(SingleThreadWatchDog.java:88)

    at org.jetel.graph.runtime.WatchDog.call(WatchDog.java:266)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.CloverEngineImpl.execute(CloverEngineImpl.java:92)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.CloverEngineImpl.execute(CloverEngineImpl.java:151)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.clover.impl.CloverEngineImpl.execute(CloverEngineImpl.java:37)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.impl.DefaultGraphExecutor.execute(DefaultGraphExecutor.java:85)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.module.datamapper.api.DataMapperHelper.execute(DataMapperHelper.java:38)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor48.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.datamapper.ui.graph.service.impl.SingleGraphLauncher.launch(SingleGraphLauncher.java:82)

    at com.mulesoft.mule.datamapper.ui.utils.RunGraphJob.run(RunGraphJob.java:59)

    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)

Caused by: org.jetel.exception.TransformException: Message: Transform failed!

    at org.jetel.component.DataRecordTransform.transformOnError(DataRecordTransform.java:132)

    at org.jetel.component.Reformat.execute(Reformat.java:273)

    at org.jetel.graph.Node.run(Node.java:493)

    ... 13 more

Caused by: org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException: Execution of the expression "//MEL
//START -> DO NOT REMOVE
output.__id = str2long(input.__id);
//END -> DO NOT REMOVE

String streetnumaddress = input.streetAddress;
String[] parts = streetnumaddress.split(",");
String streetnumber = parts[0];
String streetaddress = parts[1];

output.blabla= "Hello";
output.telephone = input.telephoneNumber;
output.lastname= input.sn;
output.firstname= input.givenName;
output.email = input.mail;
output.city= input.l;
output.province = input.st;
output.codepostal = input.postalCode;
output.country= "CA";
output.telephoneinternet = input.telephoneNumber;
output.immeubleetsuffixe = streetnumber;
output.odonyme = streetaddress;" failed.

    at org.mule.el.mvel.DataMapperExpressionLanguage.evaluate(DataMapperExpressionLanguage.java:71)

    at com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform.transform(MelRecordTransform.java:53)

    at org.jetel.component.Reformat.execute(Reformat.java:271)

    ... 14 more

Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: cannot invoke method: split

    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.MethodAccessor.getValue(MethodAccessor.java:63)

    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.VariableAccessor.getValue(VariableAccessor.java:37)

    at org.mule.mvel2.ast.ASTNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(ASTNode.java:108)

    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.ExecutableAccessor.getValue(ExecutableAccessor.java:38)

    at org.mule.mvel2.ast.TypedVarNode.getReducedValueAccelerated(TypedVarNode.java:70)

    at org.mule.mvel2.MVELRuntime.execute(MVELRuntime.java:86)

    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getDirectValue(CompiledExpression.java:123)

    at org.mule.mvel2.compiler.CompiledExpression.getValue(CompiledExpression.java:119)

    at org.mule.mvel2.MVEL.executeExpression(MVEL.java:943)

    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionExecutor.execute(MVELExpressionExecutor.java:72)

    at org.mule.el.mvel.MVELExpressionExecutor.execute(MVELExpressionExecutor.java:35)

    at org.mule.el.mvel.DataMapperExpressionLanguage.evaluate(DataMapperExpressionLanguage.java:67)

    ... 16 more

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor59.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)

    at org.mule.mvel2.optimizers.impl.refl.nodes.MethodAccessor.getValue(MethodAccessor.java:48)

    ... 27 more
```

Comment: I am running into a similar error with datamapper. Were you able to find a fix for this?

Comment: I scrapped the DataMapper and used a Groovy script it's much more flexible. I surrounded the streetnumaddress with an if not null condition. Also Datamapper is only available for paid version.

Comment: Could you post your groovy script as an answer?

Comment: I just posted it, hope it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed it for a Groovy script instead as such :

```
String acronymeministere = "YOOOO;"
String pays = "CA;"
String finalString = ""

payload.each { p ->

    String telephoneinternet = ";";
    String telephone = ";";
    String telecopieur = ";"
    String nomdefamille = ";";
    String prenom = ";";
    String initale =";"
    String qualificateurdegen = ";"
    String email = ";";
    String immeubleetsuffixe = ";"
    String odonyme = ";"
    String ville = ";";
    String province = ";";
    String codepostal = ";";
    String casepostale = ";"
    String bureau = ";"
    String etage = ";"
    String localisation = ";"
    String edifice = ";"
    String autres =";"

    if(p.streetAddress != null){
        String streetnumaddress = p.streetAddress;
        String[] parts = streetnumaddress.split(",");
        immeubleetsuffixe = parts[0].trim() + immeubleetsuffixe
        odonyme = parts[1].trim() + odonyme
    }

    telephoneinternet = p.telephoneNumber.toString().trim() + telephoneinternet
    telephone = p.telephoneNumber.toString().trim() + telephone
    nomdefamille = p.sn.toString().trim() + nomdefamille
    prenom = p.givenName.toString().trim() + prenom
    email = p.mail.toString().trim()    + email
    ville = p.l.toString().trim() + ville
    province = p.st.toString().trim() + province
    codepostal = p.postalCode.toString().trim() + codepostal


    finalString += ('"' + acronymeministere+telephoneinternet+telephone+telecopieur+nomdefamille
        +prenom+initale+qualificateurdegen+email+immeubleetsuffixe
        +odonyme+ville+province+codepostal+casepostale+pays+bureau+
        etage+localisation+edifice+autres+ '"'+'\n')
}

return finalString
```

Comment: Great solution! Also, if you're familiar with [MVEL](http://mvel.codehaus.org/Language%20Guide%20for%202.0), you could have used a MEL `expression-component`.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to split the string and assign the values to out put values in data mapper like you are trying to do.

You are getting a null pointer exception, which means your "input.streetAddress" could be null. 
can you please check you input street address data is present.

-Vinay